# Measure differential equation with Radon-Nikodym derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

I have the following generalization of ODE to measures. Let $M$ be the space of measures on $[0, 1]$. Consider function $\varphi\colon M \to ([0, 1]\to \mathbb R)$.

Find a curve (in the space of measures) $\mu_t$, $\mu_t \in M$ for each $t$, such that the following holds:

$$\mu_0=\hat \mu_0 \text{ (known initial condition),}$$
$$\frac{d\mu_{t+h}}{d\mu_t}=1+h\varphi[\mu_t]+o(h),\quad h\to 0,$$
where left-hand side is Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\mu_{t+h}$ with respect to $\mu_t$.

This is an attempt to formalize a kind of measure differential equation that can be also be written in the following way: find a curve $\mu_t$ in the space of measures such that for any measurable $E$,

$$\frac{\partial \mu_t(E)}{\partial t}=\int_E \varphi[\mu_t](x)d\mu_t(x).$$

Are there any theory on such equations? Existence and uniqueness of solutions?

Comment: Did you ever find out more about this? I would also be interested if there were existing theories/methods.

Comment: @wintergreen_plaza unfortunately, no.

Comment: If a probability density function is an example of a Radon–Nikodym derivative, and Kolmogorov equations are PDEs that describe the time evolution of a probability density function, is that similar to what you are thinking of?